# number theory based on powers of 2

Tags: number-theory, congruences

if $2^{s}$ is found by rearranging the digits of $2^r$ prove that $r=s$. 
I suspect that this question requires congruence but i need help.the 2 numbers have same digits, and the base 2 must have something to with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Thomas Andrew's answer,
$2^s-2^r=2^r(2^{s-r}-1)$,
but 9 does not divide
$2^k-1$ until $k=6$,
contradicting his observation
that $s-r \le 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The numbers are congruent modulo nine, and the difference between $r$ and $s$ has to be less than $4$.